# How do you choose what bass notes to play using a lead sheet

Tags: lead-sheets

My problem is that if I look at the chords of a lead sheet (treble staff) almost none of my bass notes sound right -- not even the roots, 3rds, 5ths or 7ths.

Take a slow song like the old standard The Wayward Wind, popularly sung by Gogi Grant. The first page's chords shown are C, C7, F, Fm, G7. The bass only plays a note on beats 1 and 3.

I believe she's singing in a different key, but even if I try any, most of the roots still sound bad.

Shouldn't it be easy to play good-sounding bass notes on beats 1 and 3 of such a simple song? I'm sure not having much luck....

Thx.

Link to the song:

Comment: If you are trying to play with recording that is available online, linking to it might be helpful?  What key are you trying to play in?  Note that sometimes recordings are sped up, or slowed down such that you'd have to tune between notes to match it.

Comment: I'd be surprised if she is singing in a different key. Can I suggest that they maybe de-tuned a little to support her voice and are actually playing different notes than those notated ? Its not uncommon to detune by a semitone, early U2 is commonly recorded to an e flat tuning. Thats maybe why it may sound wrong to you

Comment: Link to the song: [youtube.com/watch?v=2cQUVtbztEs](http://Link%20to%20the%20song:%20youtube.com/watch?v=2cQUVtbztEs%20Thanks,%20everyone.) (Copy and paste if necessary.) Thanks, everyone.

Comment: "nothing sounds right..." explain more about what you're doing. Playing what? bass, piano? Your playing doesn't sound right with what? the record? just the bass line? bass against chords? Are you sure you're tuned properly? Etc.

Comment: Mods - please check this out. 5 dvs, usual lack of explanation for ANY. Someone's playing silly games?

Comment: You are not asking for the bass line that is played in the video, yes? You ask which notes can be played to this chords to have a fitting bass line?

Comment: What do mods think? It's a phenomenon that's never ocurred in all the years I've visited. Could be that all the answers (and the question) are completely wrong - but I doubt it.

Comment: Be nice to have at least a comment from a mod or two! Or have they joined Monica...

Answer (score -1):

You couldn't go wrong with a simple: C,G,C,G,F,C,F,C,G,D,G,D here. The melody (which I don't remember that well) may be dissonant against the accompaniment if the phrases (at least the last phrase) resolves nicely.

I'd probably not get away with it in some bands but I might play C,Bb,A,G followed by F,C,Bb,Ab,G,D,G. The first phrase gets the C7 anticipated (the piece doesn't depend on the C-C7 but uses the C7 to go to F. Cf. Crazy Arms or Twist Again the the contrast of a triad vs a seventh matters.) With a little work, I try to get the Ab from the Fm chord in just to have a half-step approach to the G (not sure this would work.)

With a livelier walking bass (on all 4 beats or at least 1,3,4 like a rumba) there are other possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

C C/E F F/Ab G G/B (the bass plays root not and 3rd - also possible with passing tones: 1231 on  each beat)

Alternativ the bass line could be C Bb A Ab G B  C but this shouldn‘t be doubled in another voice.

Comment: There must be a music expert round here who knows more than all others. But it seems he isn‘t able to poste an answer ... ;)

Comment: Honestlly, no, the asylum is missing one, and he's ended up here!

Answer (score -1):

The version I just listened to was coming over in key **B**. Maybe a strange key for an orchestra, but that's it. So trying to follow key C chords on any instrument just won't work.

Listen to the recording, and there's a basic 1 and 5 played on bass. It *has* to work, on beats 1 and 3. It cannot not work! It's the simplest bass line possible, really. I think your problem is the tuning discrepancy.

Incidentally, while Gogi is in key B, Patsy Cline is in key A♭, and Frank Ifield was in key E♭. Seems no-one does it in key C...

Answer (score -1):

Jazz chord symbols assume root position chords.

`C7` means play `C` in the bass.

If there is an inversion with another chord tone in the bass, it is indicated with a *slash*.

`C7/G` means play `G` in the bass.

Sometimes people don't use the slashes and apparently expect you to know when common progressions use inversions.

Like this...

[image]

...versus this...

[image]

Comment: Second bar in 1st version doesn't reflect the second bar in the 2nd version too well, although I realise that's not the point.